# position heading at bottom of container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float a heading tag to the bottom of a li tag as in the image below. So even when the text is short, it always stays at the bottom and only extends above.

The heading seems to overspill out of the li. Any help is most appreciated.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/JtVGp/1/

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li style="float:left; width:70px; height:90px; margin:0 10px 10px 0; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; border: 4px solid #0CF; padding:10px; position:relative;"> 
      <a title href="#">
            <div style="background:#9F0; width: 50px; height: 50px; float:left; display:block"></div>
            <h2 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:right; bottom: 10px; position:absolute ">ANOTHER APP</h2>
      </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you think is wrong with the demo. It seems quite close match to your mockup image.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand the question, but at least in Chrome, your fiddle work the same way your image shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly what you want:

add `right: 5px` to your header - this will space it from the right edge of the li so it won't look like it's overspilling

you can play with the values of `right` and `width` to achieve the right result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hey add one line css in your code

define white space in your css as like this

```
 white-space: pre;
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/JtVGp/2/

Comment: this is of no use for what he wants to achieve, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html#link2